# Spring JPA and Hibernate slow query log

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring JPA application which uses hibernate and mysql. I would like to log slow running database queries on this application. Hibernate provides an option to configure 'hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS' (with log level org.hibernate.SQL_SHOW: INFO). However using this option will log SQL with parameter values set.

Is there an option in hibernate to replace the parameter values with '?'.

ex: insert into customer (name) values (**?**)

instead of

insert into customer (name) values ('**John**')

FYI, Setting the log level on org.hibernate.SQL to DEBUG will log the SQL with ? instead of parameter values. This will print all the SQL in the logs, In my case I only want to log slow running queries

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

(Maybe Hibernate is doing more than necessary...)

MySQL optionally creates "slowlog" that contains details (in including 'John') on the slow query.  However, the next thing that can be done is to "digest" the log.  This will replace strings and numbers with ? or S (for string).  So, if you can bypass Hibernate and get the log, use `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t` to do the digesting.  This gives a much shorter output file (by combining queries with the same 'digest' or 'signature').

The underlying setting is `long_query_time`; it is a number of "seconds" and can be a fractional value such as "0.5" for half a second.  Setting it to 0 would capture all queries, which it sounds like you don't want.  (I almost never go much below `1`.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this approach will not work for us due to the compliance reasons. Based on my research it sounds like neither MySQL or hibernate has options for what I am looking for. I will have to write my own code to find the slow running queries.